# PHP Check if <ul> has ended IF it exists

Tags: php, list, blogs

I have my blog generate a preview by taking the first 300 characters and cut off the last whole word. My problem is, when I have a list near the top of the blog it is sometimes included in the preview, however the end list tag usually never is. So how can I check the `$preview` variable for a starting list tag, and if it is found, check for an ending tag and if it's not there add one.

All the code for my preview.

```
$preview = wordwrap($content, 300);
$preview = explode("\n", $preview);
$preview = $preview[0] . "...";
```

Comment: It would help to know what you've done so far, can you show us your code?

Comment: You really can't use string functions like `substr` to do what you're trying to do. You need to use a DOM parser and actually pull out the first 300 characters worth of *content*, not just the first 300 characters of *markup*. How are you currently preventing your preview from chopping off text between `<a></a>` or `<p></p>` or in the middle of an `<img src=.../>`, or literally any other HTML tag which might appear? And appending a `</ul>` won't even be enough. What about the final `</li>` which will probably (but not definitely) also be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( strpos($preview, '<ul>') !== false && strpos($preview, '</ul>') === false ) {
    $preview .= '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Fixes the problem I was about ask. A+

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
if ( !strpos($preview, '<ul>') && !strpos($preview, '</ul>') ) {
    $preview .= '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: You're missing an exclamation mark in front of the first `strpos`.  Since it should be `is not false`.  I've tested it, and it doesn't work without it ;)

Comment: So then I'd have to remove the ! in front of the second strpos since I'm check if it's NOT there.

Comment: There's something wrong. You can test your program with string `"zHello world"` and you will know what I mean :)

Comment: And the problem is not that simple as it seems to be

Comment: @Zoltan Toth: Please use `===` or `!==` operator.  Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.